# Looping a ReactJS component inside of its parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component imported that returns a bunch of cards but I want to style this in a row instead of a column and it seems the way to do that is to loop the component as a `<li>` and then adding css but I cannot seem to make the component loop correctly.

the component looks like this inside of the parent element:

```
<div id="newsFeed" className='feed'>
<Feed theme={this.state.theme} articles = {this.state.articles} />
  </div>
```

I have tried solutions such as:

```
var feedContent = <Feed theme={this.state.theme} articles = {this.state.articles} />
///////////////////////
{feedContent.map(item => <Feed key={item} value={item} />)}
    </div>
```

but cannot seem to find any luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you should call map on an array, so is there any variable which is an array that specifies how many cards have to be rendered in your code...?

Comment: There is no set amount the amount of cards rendered it is just what is returned by a series of  REST calls

Comment: where does `Feed` come from? Are you importing it from a library or you have implemented it yourself? In case of latter, please add implementation of Feed to your question

Comment: Please post the code for `Feed`

Comment: This is ```<Feed />``` ```function Feed(props) {
return <div>
        {props.articles.totalResults > 0 ?
        props.articles.articles.map(article => <NewsCard article={article}/>)
                : <NewsCard article={{title:'No News'
                                , publication_date: Date.now()
                                , main_image_url:'REST'
                                , url:'https://about:blank'
                                , author: 'None'
                                , category: 'REST'
                        }} />
                }
        </div>;
}
```

Comment: I took the URL strings out for the REST because I was going over the character limit

Comment: okay so the data you recieve in rest call has some format right is that an array... so you can know how many feeds you got back from rest call

Comment: Whether or not I can see the amount of feeds I do not want to limit them I'm just using a flex box and am trying to scroll the overflow along the x axis

Answer (score 1):

map is a built in array method that is used a bunch in React. You need to use it on an array or else you will throw an error.  I am assuming the value for articles is an array here:

```js
//Feed component
class Feed extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      articles = [] 
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => { // maybe call an API to populate the articles array }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <ul className="someClass" >
        {this.state.articles.map((item, index) => <li key={index} className="someOtherClass">{item}</li>)}
      </ul>
    );
  }

}
```

alternatively you could create a li component, perhaps called FeedItem, import it and map it with the value prop from each item in the articles array.

```js
// render method for Feed Component
render = () => {
  return(
    <ul className="someClass">
      {this.state.articles.map((item, index) => <FeedItem key={index} value={item} />)}
    </ul>
  );
}

// FeedItem component
const FeedItem = ({value}) => {
  return(
    <li className="someOtherClass">{value}</li>
  );
}
```

so, you are using map to create a list with the items in your articles array, and the map function loops through each article and returns a list component. Hopefully this helps! here's the React docs for reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

note: React docs advise against using an index as a key, but I don't know if your article array elements contain something unique.  If they do (like an id of some kind), use that instead of index.

Comment: I am still trying to integrate your solution to my code, do you think there is anyway to loop ```<Feed />``` as it is seen in the parent component?

Comment: if you use the following as a child of your ```<div id="newsFeed" className='feed'></div>``` dom element (from your first snipped): ```{this.state.articles.map((item, index) => <Feed key={index} value={item} />)}```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the approach.

I'd recommend you create an Article component, example:

```
function Article({ title }) {
  <div>
    {title}
  <div>
}
```

After that, you might use the articles array to show each one:

```
//Feed component
this.state.articles.map((article, i) => <Article title={article.title}>)
```

In that way you can stylize the articles component as you want.

Comment: That is a good idea but I do not think I can make this new component on my own, this is a collaboration project and ```<Feed />``` was made by my coworker

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out with simple CSS believe it or not. Basically `<Feed />` was wrapped in a div in the parent component and was not responding to Flexbox CSS code, however, After I used changed the className of the div that was wrapping the component inside of its `<div>` within its own file the div responded to CSS! Thank you so much for your help everyone, I appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding a className to the div that is the parent of the cards? Use that class to apply a flex display for example, and see what that gives you. If Newscard has a fixed width of 100% by chance, of course you'll need to adjust that to a small percentage / width to suit your needs.

Comment: I have tried that but it does not work here is the CSS for the ```</div>```                   ```.blog-card {
  display: inline-flex ;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: start;
  justify-items: start;
  align-self: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin-bottom: 1.6%;
  background: rgba(68, 78, 90, 0.2);
  line-height: 1.0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 0;
}```